# Whats the domain of the sample average in Strong Law of Large Numbers?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

The strong law of large numbers states that the sample average converges almost surely to the expected value $\overline{X}_n\ \xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}}\ \mu \qquad\mathrm{when}\ n \to \infty$ .

That is,$$\Pr\left( \lim_{n\to\infty}\overline{X}_n = \mu \right) = 1.$$

I want to ask whats the domain of the random variable $\overline{X}_n$, given that all $X_n$ have same domain $\Omega$?

For the coin tossing problem $\Omega =\{H,T\} $ and $X_n(H)=1 \quad and \quad X_n(T)=0 \quad\forall n $ so, if the domain of $\overline{X}_n$ was $\Omega$ the $\overline{X}_n(H)=1 \quad \overline{X}_n(T)=0 \quad \forall n$, so $\Pr\left({\omega \in \Omega : \overline{X}_n(\omega)=1/2}\right)=0$ , which is not what strong law says.

I want to know whats the domain of this random variable $\overline{X}_n$?

Comment: Domain of $\overline X_n$ is $\Omega^n$.

Comment: For the coin tossing problem, neither the domain $\Omega=\{H,T\}$ nor any domain $\Omega=\{H,T\}^n$ is suitable. To define a whole sequence $(X_n)$, hence every $\bar X_n$ necessary to even *state* that $\bar X_n\to\mu$, one option is to consider $\Omega=\{H,T\}^\mathbb N$ and to define each $X_n$ by $X_n(\omega)=\omega_n$ where $\omega=(\omega_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ (these are often called the *canonical* sample space and the canonical process on it). In any case, the domain of every $X_n$ and every $\bar X_n$ should be the same, and should be large enough to "receive" ...

Comment: ... an i.i.d. sequence of Bernoulli random variables. Another choice is $\Omega=[0,1]$ with some suitable sigma-algebras and random variables $X_n$ (this one being called the *standard* space).

Comment: So http://math.stackexchange.com/users/6179/did  you mean is kind of lifted to the space $\Omega^\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: *with some suitable sigma-algebra (singular).

Comment: Could anyone provide a reference (textbook e.g.,) so that I can read this more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if we could define the $\overline{X}_n: \Omega^n\to \{0,1\}$, we would end up with many random variables defined in different probability spaces. In that situation we would not be able to make any sense of the notion "probability that the sequence of $\overline{X}_n$ converges", because we wouldn't have a fixed probability measure to consider all of the outcomes of the $\{\overline X_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ at once to assign a probability.

What we need is a probability measure defined on *sequences of outcomes*. More precisely, the sample space is the set of sequences with values in $\Omega = \{H,T\}$, that is, $\Omega^{\mathbb N}$.

In this setting, if $\omega = (\omega_1,\omega_2,\dots)\in \Omega^{\mathbb N}$, then

$$X_k(\omega) = \cases{1 & $\text{if } {\omega_k} = H$\\ 0 & $\text{if } {\omega_k} = T$}$$
and
$$\overline{X}_n(\omega) = \frac{X_1(\omega)+\dots+X_n(\omega)}{n}.$$

Comment: Reaching a correct answer is much preferable to deleting a first version, of course. +1.

Comment: @Did Agreed. Thank you!

Comment: Should we define $X_k(\omega)=X_k(\omega_k)$ in general?

Comment: @TrungDung could you rephrase the question? $X_k$ as defined in the answer is a function on the sample space of sequences of elements in $\Omega$, not on individual elements of $\Omega$, while the $\omega_k$ stand for one of these individual elements

Comment: Thanks! What I understand is that there are two versions, $X_k^{(ori)}$ (originally defined on $\Omega$) and $X_k^{(ext)}$ (extended defined on $\Omega^{\mathbb{N}})$. My question is that: $X_k^{(ext)}(\omega) = X_k^{(ori)}(\omega_k)$.

Comment: @TrungDung There is only one original version defined on $\Omega$, the random variable $X$. The $X_k$ are defined on sequences of $\Omega$ outcomes, not on $\Omega$. The assumption the OP made that "All the $X_k$ have the same domain" was misleading. The book I studied with, Williams _Probability with Martingales_, has some sections about probability spaces of sequences: **8.7**, 4.5-4.7, and appendix to chapter 9.